# scraping the text from source code using python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape google search results using python and selenium. I'm able to get only the first search result. Here is the code I'm using.

```
        driver.get(url)
        res = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.g')
        link = res[0].find_element_by_tag_name("a")
        href = link.get_attribute("href")
```

How can I get all the search results?

Comment: What have you tried to get more than one result?

Comment: I utilized the solution proposed by Andersson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get list of links (from first page only. If you need to scrape more pages, you need to click "Next" button in a loop and append results from following pages) as below:

```
href = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.g a')]
```

P.S. You also might use solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623798/google-search-with-python-requests-library) to get results as GET request response with `requests` lib