# Connecting django Query with Google search engine

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am trying to take a string query  'q' from user in my django website and do the following

1. Do  a google search on 'q'.
2. take the first link after doing  the google search on 'q',
3. scrape some data parameters (like views on the review etc.) from the websites, arrange them using these parameters and then display the results.

I have used google custom search API to make a search engine. I have made this search engine for a specific website.
I am unable to do the third step. It seems like I can only use some predefined structured data. But unable to scrape data parameters for customizing search order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google search with python requests library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623798/google-search-with-python-requests-library)